# SQL Server 2008 XPath Equivalent to preceding-sibling axis locator

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have some MathML that contains tags that identify various function calls (though this scenario can apply to any XML).

A sample would be:

```
<math>
  <apply>
    <ci>IIF</ci>
    <apply>
      <eq />
      <apply>
        <ci>DDOutputB60</ci>
        <ci>Index</ci>
      </apply>
      <cn>0</cn>
    </apply>
    <cn>0</cn>
    <apply>
      <ci>DDOutputB60</ci>
      <ci>Index</ci>
    </apply>
  </apply>
</math>
```

As you can see, this particular sample identifies two function calls - but both are to the same function (DDOutputB60)

I am attempting to write some SQL to list the DISTINCT functions but need to do this in the XPath and not in a wrapper SELECT statement that selects DISTINCT from the result set.

(As an aside, the reason for this is that this is the member SQL for a recursive CTE and DISTINCT or GROUP BY are not allowed)

I am led to believe that the following is valid XPath that will select distinct values but is not supported in SQL Server 2008:

```
COLUMN.nodes('(//ci[not(text() = preceding-sibling::ci/text())])')
```

Can anyone suggest an XPath equivalent that will work in SQL Server 2008?
Perhaps the >> or << node comparison operators might help, but I'm not an expert. Yet.

Thanks in advance.

@Ravi: the desired output would be the result of the .nodes(...) sql function which I assume would look in this case like:

```
        <ci>DDOutputB60</ci>
```

It would be a single node result as the duplicate has been removed.

Comment: As an extra comment, I do need the result as a node-set and not a list of values as it's used in a cross-apply query...

Comment: Can you provide the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps the >> or << node comparison operators might help, but I'm not an expert. Yet.

*Yes this is what you need*

- Here example in those two answer:

[Getting the following sibling in an XPath when “following” axis is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238844/getting-the-following-sibling-in-an-xpath-when-following-axis-is-not-supported)

[Get followin sibling in SQL Server XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253758/get-followin-sibling-in-sql-server-xpath)