# Get followin sibling in SQL Server XPath

Tags: sql-server, xpath

Since SQL Server does not support following-sibling axis - what is the best way to get it? Let's say I have XML like this and I would like to get the first 'b' node after a node matching the value 'dog':

```
<root>
    <a>cat</a>
    <b>Cats don't like milk</b>
    <a>dog</a>
    <b>Dogs like everything</b>
</root>
```

Comment: Does `<a>it's a dog, yo</a>` meet your criteria "containing the value 'dog'"?

Comment: No, I'm looking for exact match. Edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
declare @X xml = '
<root>
    <a>cat</a>
    <b>Cats don''t like milk</b>
    <a>dog</a>
    <c>not this</c>
    <b>Dogs like everything</b>
    <b>and not this</b>
</root>'

select @X.query('(/root/b[. >> (/root/a[. = "dog"])[1]])[1]')
```

Comment: How would you express that for this query?

    SELECT
    c.row.value(N'text()[1]','varchar(3)') as animal
    ,c.row.value(N'','varchar(50)') as preference
    From
    @X.nodes('root/a') c(row)