# Read XML with others fields in T-SQL

Tags: sql, xml

let's say I have a table with the following columns:

```
EmpID, EmpName, PHONEXML
```

With PHONEXML Like:

```
<phoneType>Home</phoneType>
<phoneNum>123456789</phoneNum>
<phoneType>Work</phoneType>
<phoneNum>234567890</phoneNum>
```

How can I get 2 rows with :

```
EmpName, phoneType, phoneNum
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over XML structure, I'd suggest to wrap data for each phone information within common parent node, for example :

```
<phone>
   <phoneType>Home</phoneType>
   <phoneNum>123456789</phoneNum>
</phone>
<phone>
   <phoneType>Work</phoneType>
   <phoneNum>234567890</phoneNum>
</phone>
```

Then you can query the data this way :

```
select
    s.EmpName
    ,m.c.value('(phoneType)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PhoneType
    ,m.c.value('(phoneNum)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PhoneNum
from MyTable as s
    outer apply s.PHONEXML.nodes('/phone') as m(c)
```

**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5b8c/7/0)**

Without common parent node the task seems way more complicated. We'll need to select one type of phone information and then get the other information using sibling relation, for example :

```
select
    s.EmpName
    ,m.c.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PhoneType
    ,m.c.value('(following-sibling::phoneNum)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PhoneNum
from MyTable as s
    outer apply s.PHONEXML.nodes('/phoneType') as m(c)
```

But turned out [SQL Server doesn't support `following-sibling`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238844/getting-the-following-sibling-in-an-xpath-when-following-axis-is-not-supported) or `preceding-sibling` axis.