# SQL Server : how to parse this xml into table columns?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to parse below xml into table data. However, I am only getting one row. What do I need to do to get all the data? I have a [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57935/224) to demonstrate this as well.

```
INSERT BATCHES (BatchID, RawXML)
VALUES (1, '
    <ParamData>
        <moduleRole>
            <moduleId>1</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>2</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>8</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>3</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>255</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>8</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>16</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>64</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>
            <moduleId>128</moduleId>
            <bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>
        </moduleRole>
    </ParamData>
');

SELECT  
    b.BatchID,
    x.XmlCol.value('(moduleId)[1]','INT') AS moduleId,
    x.XmlCol.value('(bmRoleId)[1]','INT') AS bmRoleId
FROM
    Batches b
CROSS APPLY 
    b.RawXml.nodes('/ParamData/moduleRole') x(XmlCol);
```

Comment: How many `<moduleId>1</moduleId><bmRoleId>4</bmRoleId>` you have for each `<moduleRole>`? It doesn't change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think to shred the XML on `moduleId`, then select current element and the nearest following sibling `bmRoleId` element :

```
SELECT  b.BatchID,
        x.XmlCol.value('.','INT') AS moduleId,
        x.XmlCol.value('following-sibling::bmRoleId)[1]','INT') AS bmRoleId
FROM    Batches b
CROSS APPLY b.RawXml.nodes('/ParamData/moduleRole/moduleId') x(XmlCol);
```

Unfortunately, `following-sibling` axis isn't supported by SQL Server, so we need to use the trick mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238844/getting-the-following-sibling-in-an-xpath-when-following-axis-is-not-supported) :

```
SELECT  b.BatchID,
        x.XmlCol.value('.','INT') AS moduleId,
        x.XmlCol.value('let $c := . return (../bmRoleId[. >> $c])[1]','INT') AS bmRoleId
FROM    Batches b
CROSS APPLY b.RawXml.nodes('/ParamData/moduleRole/moduleId') x(XmlCol);
```

**<kbd>[`sqlfiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57935/235)</kbd>**

This part `return (../bmRoleId[. >> $c])[1]`, get all `bmRoleId` that located after current `moduleId` (referenced by `$c`), and then limit the result to the first of such `bmRoleId` in document order

Comment: I like this answer (+1 from my side), but I think it was easier to use a numbers table...

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather solve this with a numbers table. In my example I'll create one *on-the-fly* from `master..spt_values`, which contains about 2.500 entries. This should suffice. We do not need the values, just the return of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH Numbers AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT b.BatchID
     ,b.RawXml.value(N'(/ParamData/moduleRole/moduleId)[sql:column("Nr")][1]','int') AS moduleId
     ,b.RawXml.value(N'(/ParamData/moduleRole/bmRoleId)[sql:column("Nr")][1]','int') AS bmRoleId
FROM Numbers
CROSS JOIN [BATCHES] AS b
WHERE b.RawXml.exist(N'(/ParamData/moduleRole/moduleId)[sql:column("Nr")]')=1;
```

The result

```
1   1   4
1   2   8
1   3   255
1   8   4
1   16  4
1   64  4
1   128 4
```

### Hint

It would help - if performance matters - to use `TOP` before `ROW_NUMBER` to limit the numbers for the `CROSS JOIN` to an appropriate count...