# Get the node following a selected node

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath

I have the following (cut down) xml in a sql column

```
<Values>
  <Value>
    <N>Test</N>
    <V>FindMe</V>
  </Value>
  <Value>
    <N>Test</N>
    <V>NotMe</V>
  </Value>
  <Value>
    <N>Other Value</N>
    <V>NotMe</V>
  </Value>
</Values>
```

I am trying to get the value of `V`, following the first `N` with a value of `Test`

I have tried using `following-sibling`, but that apparently is not supported in whatever version of XPATH Sql Server 2008 uses.

I have arrived at the following query, based on [Gunther's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260223/14965516):

```
/Values/Value/V[. >> /Values/Value/N[. = 'Test'][1]][1]
```

Which when tried online, returns multiple rows, but when tried in the following SQL

```
SELECT
    A.x,
    A.x.query('/Values/Value/V[. >> /Values/Value/N[. = ''Test''][1]][1]')
FROM (SELECT CAST('<Values><Value><N>Test</N><V>FindMe</V></Value><Value><N>Other Value</N><V>NotMe</V></Value></Values>' AS XML) x) A
```

Has the following error

```
XQuery [A.x.query()]: '>>' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'element(N,xdt:untyped) *'
```

I've tried the following variations on the query, but all have had the same error

```
/Values/Value/V[. >> /Values/Value/N[. = 'Test'][1]][1]
/Values/Value/V[. >> /Values/Value[N = 'Test'][1]][1]
/Values/Value/V[. >> /Values/Value[N = 'Test']/N[1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
/Values/Value[N='Test'][1]/V
```

Comment: It did, excellent.
It seems I overcomplicated things!